# Is it possible to create a pop-up figure that yields a truncated cone?

Tags: geometry

#### Problem

I have a geometrical problem. Consider the cone in the figure below. Is it possible to create a two-dimensional shape that extends to the three dimensional truncated cone? The idea is to fold some paper to create something like a popup figure.

[image: truncated cone]

I first want to hold something in my hand that is essentially in the xy-plane below. I then want to pull on it, to extend it along the x-axis.

#### Question

Is this possible? If yes, how?

#### Background

Don't laugh at my question, please :-). I want to create a prop for a lecture. By having a 2D shape that I pull apart to obtain a 3D shape, I can explain the principle of a lossless relaxation in convex optimization theory to students. See doi: 10.2514/1.27553.

Comment: A cone is a [ruled surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) so I can imagine you could maybe build a frame with jointed rods attached, which lays flat, but such that when you hang it the rods form the surface of the cone.

Comment: Only a developable surface can be made by folding a flat sheet of paper. Some ruled surfaces are not developable. Cones are developable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a two-dimensional shape that extends to the three dimensional truncated cone?

Yes, it's possible. You are looking at it at your left figure: A partial annulus. If you carve on paper or wireframe any annulus missing a sector of angle $0<\theta\le\Phi$, for some good accomodating $\Phi$, say, $\Phi\le\pi/2$, then when you fold the annulus and join its end points you will get a truncated cone or frustum.

If you want to cut it to exact specifications, take a look first at what's called "truncated cone development" in Euclidean Geometry.

[image]